# How to change column data type to DOUBLE in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to change the data type of an existing column of a particular table using below statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname DOUBLE;
```

but it throws following **error**,

> SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword 00905. 00000 - "missing keyword"
>   *Cause: *Action:

Can anyone help to avoid this error or else help to find the root cause of this error? Thank you

Comment: You tagged mysql but error looks like an Oracle one

Comment: Changed accordingly.

Comment: Use BINARY_DOUBLE for double datatype in oracle. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want [`BINARY_DOUBLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1834):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname BINARY_DOUBLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "DOUBLE" is not a valid PLSQL keyword.  See Table 4 - 1 in the following article:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/PLS23/ch4.htm#plsql%20tabs

Please try "FLOAT".  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NUMBER datatype，But this must be NULL can be changed

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname double;
```